# How to perform graph embedding on a DAG graph with point weights and restore the resulting embedding vector to the DAG with point weights?

Tags: embeddings

How to perform graph embedding on a directed acyclic graph with point weights and restore the resulting embedding vector to the directed acyclic graph with point weights?